# Dropzone.js: Custom file browser - add file that's already been uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropzone.js

Before you start tutting, this isn't the usual 'can't load my files from the server' post...

I want to give users the option to see files on the server already in a bootstrap modal, then allow them to select given files. On selection, I want to close the modal and send them to dropzone to load in.

I'm sure mockfile is the way to go. I'm just not sure where to start.

- how do I pass image URLs to dropzone programmatically? I don't think I want to get dropzone to re-initialise as if they click 'browse files' more than once, then they will loose previous images.

I hope I have explained myself ok. I can't see an 'addFiles' option and am not sure how to pass mockfiles after the dropzone has been loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should take a look at https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

Comment: Thanks Bass, I don't really see how that helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mockfile = { name: fileName, size: fileSize };
dropZoneObject.options.addedfile.call(dropZoneObject, mockfile);
dropZoneObject.options.thumbnail.call(dropZoneObject, mockfile, fileImageURL);
```

Ofcourse you replace filename, fileSize and fileImageURL and add as many files as you have on the server.

Comment: Thanks potatopeelings. This looks very promising. Currently I am getting `Cannot read property 'addedfile' of undefined`. As I am adding from a Bootstrap ajax modal, I guess it can't find the instance. I'll have a little pay and see what I can come up with to get it work.